# Why do base Windows Forms form class with generic types stop the designer loading?

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I am trying to have a base [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) form which holds common functionality and controls - but also holds references to a class which requires a type for its methods. Each form will represent a different type, so I thought that I could do something along the lines of this:

```
public partial class Base<T> : Form where T : BaseClass
{
    private GenericHandler handler = new GenericHandler();
}

public class BaseClass { }

public class GenericHandler
{
    public void DoSomethingWithInstance<T>(T instance) where T : BaseClass
    {

    }
}
```

My designer class declaration also mirrors what my form has. Now when I do my second form which represents the type `Foo`, I can't access the designer, because I get this error:

> The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the
>   classes within it can be designed. The designer inspected the
>   following classes in the file: Foo --- The base class
>   'WindowsFormsApplication1.Base' could not be loaded. Ensure the
>   assembly has been referenced and that all projects have been built.
>
> FooClass --- The base class 'WindowsFormsApplication1.BaseClass'
>   cannot be designed.

```
public partial class Foo : Base<FooClass>
{
    public Foo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class FooClass : BaseClass { }
```

Why does this happen/what am I doing wrong or are there any other methods to do this?

Comment: Not an explanation, but note that you can (and I do) work around the issue by not having a generic base class, but by having an intermediate base class that itself derives from a generic class: `Foo : FooBase`, `FooBase : Base<FooClass>`. There is nothing at all in the definition of `FooBase` other than its base.

Comment: @hvd this works a treat. I'd accept it as an answer but it's a comment.

Comment: I posted it as a comment because it doesn't answer the question you asked; I think you shouldn't accept it. Even if the question you asked may no longer matter to you :)

Comment: Background material (Visual Studio Magazine): *[Tap the Power of Inherited WinForms](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2005/05/01/tap-the-power-of-inherited-winforms.aspx)*

Comment: This particular problem might be covered in the ***answers*** to *[Is visual inheritance supported by WinForms Designer in MVS 2008 for C++/CLI?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e21a3b47-4ec9-425e-845c-a9bea5b01c29/is-visual-inheritance-supported-by-winforms-designer-in-mvs-2008-for-ccli?forum=winformsdesigner)* (inserting a class between the generic thingy and your class).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When a Windows Form or a user UserControl is loaded in the designer, basically the designer is creating an instance of the *base class* (that class that your custom form or control directly derives from) and then executes the `InitializeComponents()` method manually/explicitly through reflection to build up the intended design of your control.

In your case however it can not create an instance of the base class, because it has a generic parameter. The same thing happens if the base class of your form or your control is abstract or does not have a default constructor. In those cases the designer will also not be able to create an instance of your base class.

There is [a workaround](http://www.pocketsilicon.com/post/Using-Visual-Studio-Whidbey-to-Design-Abstract-Forms) for this using the [TypeDescriptionProviderAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptionproviderattribute.aspx) where you can give the designer a replacement class that it should instantiate instead.

Comment: Although you answer explains why it doesn't work - I can't understand how you can't instantiate a generic parameter class when if you had `Public Class GenericClass<T> { }` you could infact do `GenericClass<T> gc = new GenericClass<T>();` so why can't the initialize components handle this? Is that down to the designer not knowing what type to use in the instansiation?

Comment: `T` must be resoved to a concrete class, so no, you can't do `GenericClass<T> gc = new GenericClass<T>();`

Comment: Sorry let me re-phrase that `GenericClass<Foo> gc = new GenericClass<Foo>();` you could for arguments sake do that so because I am passing `FooClass` as the type to the base form I would of thought it could potentially drop that in during initialize component. Is there ANY way you could suggest how I might be able to get the designer loading doing something along my lines?

Comment: See the example (http://www.pocketsilicon.com/file.axd?file=2009%2f11%2fAbstractBaseClass.zip) in the workaround article of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this - I understand why I couldn't do it now. I did however use the comment to solve my issue, but you answered my question as to why.

Comment: Here's an interesting wrinkle -- If you're targeting x64, Designer won't be able to instantiate your base class (because VS is 32-bit). This had me pulling my hair out. The assembly with your base class needs to target **Any CPU** - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/967050/cannot-display-inherited-form-in-form-designer-when-base-form-defined